# Why do these MCU voltage dividers have +, -, and S on the output?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, voltage-divider

I'm looking at voltage divider modules like these to eventually measure a DC battery voltage with the range of ~10-15V:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L81QJ75/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L81QJ75)
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01HTC4XKY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HTC4XKY)

I see the input side has VCC and GND for the voltage source. On the output side I see **+**, **-**, and **S**. I assume S goes to an analog pin on the MCU, but what are +, and - for? Are they drawing power from the MCU? Is the GND on the output connect to the input GND? That seems like it might cause a problem if it ends up connected to the MCU GND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was going to guess I would say that it's probably backward-compatible with modules that once had a buffer amplifier on board.

With cost-cutting the circuit has been reduced to two resistors and the amplifier is gone, so the vestigial power supply pin remains, but is N.C.

The circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi1CZb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the measured voltage must have a common ground with the MCU ground.

The division ratio is 5:1 so a 25 input yields a 5V output (and a 16.5V input yields a 3.3V output).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why the + pin exists. Even their own sample images don't show it being used. Yes, - goes to the MCU ground, and S goes to the ADC input. If it's a problem for you to have the battery ground tied to the MCU ground, then you can't use this kind of circuit. The resistor divider needs to have the voltage you're measuring across it, *and* it has to have its bottom at the same ground reference the ADC uses, or you won't get an accurate reading. In many cases it's not a problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll just power the Arduino using a 5V stepdown from the voltage source. That way it's portable between my test setup and the final install.